# Is it Possible to Import Placeholder Values (@Value) in a Spring Java Project From an External Maven Dependency?

Tags: java, spring, maven

Currently I am designing a library to be consumed by other apps. The library is built using the Spring Framework on top of Java with Maven, and it is assumed that consuming apps will be the same (Java apps using Spring Framework and Maven). I have got the library to the point where you can simply place the dependency in your Maven pom.xml file.

I am building a demo app to test it out. On the demo app, using `@SpringBootApplication`, which contains `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on the main Application class (with the java main method) I have been able to automatically import beans from that Maven dependency. This required me to go into the library's `@Configuration` file and add `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` to all the beans that I defined, but it got that auto config working.

Problem: These beans rely on variables annotated with `@Value` in that same `@Configuration` file. When trying to build the demo app, I get error messages like this:

`Could not resolve placeholder 'proxyServerHost' in value "${proxyServerHost}"`

The corresponding code in the config file of the library looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@EnableRetry
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Value("${proxyServerHost}")
    private String proxyServerHost;

    . . .
```

I have tried changing the qualifier from private to public to no avail. But in the library's application.yml file (nested under src/main/resources) I have a corresponding entry like so:

`proxyServerHost: myproxy.org` (made up value for now)

In the demo app, these values are defined nowhere. The demo app doesn't even have a dedicated `@Configuration` class currently, and if possible, I'd like to keep it that way for maximum simplicity. I was hoping there is some way to automatically import those default values into the demo app? I'm trying to make this library as easy to use as possible, and that is part of this effort. If it is not possible that is fine, I just want to know before I require users of my library to define these values themselves. Unfortunately, extensive Googling and searching here on StackOverflow yielded no useful results to me.

Comment: Maybe set a default value in your library?  `@Value("${proxyServerHost:default_value}")`

Comment: @DirkDeyne Wow, now I feel dumb for not realizing that. Yep, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

To ensure this question has an answer, refer to Dirk Deyne's comment above. I simply needed to set a default value in my library like so:

`@Value("${proxyServerHost:default_value}")`

Thanks again Dirk Deyne! That fixed it.